# Check for filenames in BlobStorage that starts with a string in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am currently working with Powershell scripts to manage BlobStorage content in Windows-Azure. I want a script that reads content of a text file and displays names of files in BlobStorage that starts with this content. Im looking for a wildcard search that lists the names in BlobStorage which starts with the content specified in the textfile.

I have thought of a loop that searches through every line in the textfile and looks for names of files in BlobStorage that starts with the specified content in the textfile.

**If we have for example 2 rows in the textfile*:*

43345-sdfssd-42342-sdfsf

32423-asdsad-23424-dghfs

*And the filenames in BlobStorage are*:

43345-sdfssd-42342-sdfsf-250.PNG

43345-sdfssd-42342-sdfsf-650.PNG

92323-asadad-12342-sdfds-1600.PNG

I want to compare the ID in the textfile with name of BlobStorage files, and show the full filenames of all files in BlobStorage containing this ID.

**To specify this further here is what i was assuming**:

```
foreach (ID in textfile) 
{                           

  files = find files in BlobStorage with name that starts with ID (ListBlobsWithPrefix?)

  foreach (textfile in files) 
  {                
            Write filename to console
  }

}
```

So far i have managed to make a connection to my blobstorage and it works, i can list names of Blobs in the images container. I have checked that everything works with reading the textfile aswell and printing content to console. What i have not managed to do is comparing the textfile ID with the filename of the Blob in BlobStorage and print the results in BlobStorage that starts with the ID. I have tried alot of solutions without any luck.

**So far i have came up with this code:**

```
#Make a connection to my BlobStorage
$SAN = "XX"
$SAK="X"

$creds = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey($SAN, $SAK)
$client = New-Object      Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobClient("https://$SAN.blob.core.windows.net",$creds)

$bro = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.BlobRequestOptions
$bro.UseFlatBlobListing = $true

#Add $images blobcontainer and use flatbloblisting to list blobnames
$imagecontainer = $client.GetBlobDirectoryReference("images")
$images = $imagecontainer.ListBlobs($bro)

#Add textfile and assign it to a variable
$InputFile = Get-Content C:\transcript\hej.txt

#Loop to find everything in the input file and compare it to matching filenames in  blobstorage. Return filenames that starts with the ID/contains the ID in the inputfile.
foreach ($ID in Get-Content $InputFile) {
```

Appreciate further help/solution.

Comment: Is your code listing correct? Is it supposed to end in an incomplete for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have no experience with Azure, but a quick look at MSDN docs leads me to believe this would work:

```
foreach ($ID in $InputFile)
{
    $image_matches = $images | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^$ID'}

    # process matching images here
}
```